# How to compress image in j2me

Tags: image, java-me

I am making a j2me app. In this app I want to upload images more then 1 MB. But as heap size allocate is limited to 1 MB in most of the mobiles, so when I tried create input-stream of image more than 1 MB size, it throws **OutOfMemory** exception. So how I can compress image in j2me app to upload it on server.

Comment: Was your input stream buffered? What was the buffer size?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
    
    InputStream inputStream = fileConnection.openInputStream();

creating input stream in this manner. Throwing OutOfMemory Exception at this point.Please tell me the way to solve this, its really urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Do not load all the images at one time upload the image one by one and clear the previous images that will release the memory and resize the image which will reduce the image size.

Comment: @Faraz...thanks for your reply....but please tell me how to resize image without creating its input stream, problem occurs when I create input stream of large file, at that moment, OutOfMemory Exception occures.

Answer (score 0):

You resize the image as per the screen size using **scale()** method. If you want the image to fit with the phone screen size use Displayable.getWidth and getheight methods. Pass them to the Scale method as Scale(w,h) and call scale on the Image Variable. Mostly it will reduce the image size which can be handled by heap. if it is still higher, then split the image into small bytes and then upload